# CSS Opacity fix - Make transparent container stretch height of page (and hidden parts)

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, opacity

I'm using a CSS fix to ensure opacity doesn't effect inner elements and I've run into a problem. The image will only stretch to 100% of the **visible** page. My page is fairly tall however, half of it is hidden and only accessible by scrolling down. Once you scroll down though, the image container ends and I only get a solid fill color. Can this be fixed, perhaps CSS or jQuery?

**Example:**
[image]

**HTML:**

```
<body><!-- Bg Color -->
    <div class="bgImg"></div><!-- Bg Image Container -->
    <div data-role="page" class="type-home" data-theme="a">



    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body { background-color: red; }

.bgImg {
    background-image: url(../images/patterns/pattern9.png);
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0.8;);
    -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    -webkit-opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: why not add the css to your body - would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest would be to change it to position:fixed; then your background won't scroll at all

if you do want your background to scroll, then you could use javascript (or a javascript library) to get the height of your content and dynamically set the height of the background.

jquery:

```
$("div.bgImg").height($("div.type-home").height());
```

Comment: That works well actually. What complications could arise with the background not scrolling? It looks absolutely fine on my end.

Comment: no complications as far as I am aware, except that it stays stationary while the content moves over the top of it

Comment: I went with the position: fixed; approach for now due to the simplicity. Thanks